# Kinesis Firehose lambda transformation - An error occurred during JSON serialization of response

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am using below Python code (Lambda Function) for data transformation using kinesis data firehose. I am getting below error.

Code:

```
#This function is created to Transform the data from Kinesis Data Firehose -> S3 Bucket
#It converts single line json to multi line json as expected by AWS Athena best practice.
#It also removes special characters from json keys (column name in Athena) as Athena expects column names without special characters

import json
import boto3
import base64
import string
from typing import Optional, Iterable, Union

delete_dict = {sp_character: '' for sp_character in string.punctuation}
PUNCT_TABLE = str.maketrans(delete_dict)
output = []

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    for record in event['records']:
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data']).decode('utf-8')
        
        remove_special_char = json.loads(payload, object_pairs_hook=clean_keys)
        row_w_newline = str(remove_special_char) + "\n"
        row_w_newline = base64.b64encode(row_w_newline.encode('utf-8'))
        
        
        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': row_w_newline
        }
        output.append(output_record)

    print('Processed {} records.'.format(len(event['records'])))
    
    return {'records': output}
    
def strip_punctuation(s: str,
                      exclude_chars: Optional[Union[str, Iterable]] = None) -> str:
    """
    Remove punctuation and spaces from a string.

    If `exclude_chars` is passed, certain characters will not be removed
    from the string.

    """
    punct_table = PUNCT_TABLE.copy()
    if exclude_chars:
        for char in exclude_chars:
            punct_table.pop(ord(char), None)

    # Next, remove the desired punctuation from the string
    return s.translate(punct_table)

def clean_keys(o):
    return {strip_punctuation(k): v for k, v in o}
```

Error:

```
An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: b'eyd2ZXJzaW9uJzogJzAnLCAnaWQnOiAnNjFhMGI4YjQtOGRhYS0xNGMwLTllOTMtNzhhNjk0MTY0MDgxJywgJ2RldGFpbHR5cGUnOiAnQVdTIEFQSSBDYWxsIHZpYSBDbG91ZFRyYWlsJywgJ3NvdXJjZSc6ICdhd3Muc2VjdXJpdHlodWInLCAnYWNjb3VudCc6ICc5MzQ3NTU5ODkxNzYnLCAndGltZSc6ICcyMDIxLTExLTIzVDE1OjQxOjQ3WicsICdyZWdpb24nOiAndXMtZWFzdC0xJywgJ3Jlc291cmNlcyc6IFtdLCAnZGV0YWlsJzogeydldmVudFZlcnNpb24nOiAnMS4wOCcsICd1c2VySWRlbnRpdH'
     is not JSON serializable
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
        **kw).encode(obj)
      File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
        chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
      File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
        return _iterencode(o, 0)
      File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 135, in decimal_serializer
        raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

Event :

```
{'recordId': '49623720050963652954313901532126731765249603147428528130000000', 'approximateArrivalTimestamp': 1637711607661, 'data': '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'}
```

Comment: What is your `event`?

Comment: @Marcin : Event above

Comment: @Marcin: Do you have any idea on this issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70087696/python-json-serialization-error-on-returning-the-output-result?noredirect=1#comment123898256_70087696

Answer (score 0):

This code helped me with above issue

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    for record in event['records']:
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data']).decode('utf-8')
        remove_special_char = json.loads(payload, object_pairs_hook=clean_keys)
        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': base64.b64encode(json.dumps(remove_special_char).encode('utf-8') + b'\n').decode('utf-8')
        }
        output.append(output_record)

    print('Processed {} records.'.format(len(event['records'])))
    return {'records': output}
```