# python json serialization error on returning the output result

Tags: python

I am getting error on last line of this code. I am doing data transformation using python in AWS using lambda function. Weird part is it works absolutely fine in my local AWS account but fails on client system on the last line with below error.

```
import json
import boto3
import base64
import string
from typing import Optional, Iterable, Union

delete_dict = {sp_character: '' for sp_character in string.punctuation}
PUNCT_TABLE = str.maketrans(delete_dict)
output = []

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    for record in event['records']:
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data']).decode('utf-8')
        
        remove_special_char = json.loads(payload, object_pairs_hook=clean_keys)
        row_w_newline = str(remove_special_char) + "\n"
        row_w_newline = base64.b64encode(row_w_newline.encode('utf-8'))
        
        
        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': row_w_newline
        }
        output.append(output_record)

    print('Processed {} records.'.format(len(event['records'])))
    
    return {'records': output}
```

This line gives below error :

```
return {'records': output}
```

Error:

```
An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 135, in decimal_serializer
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

Output:

```
[{'recordId': '49624207526699472828556941664751397737727737843643580418000000', 'result': 'Ok', 'data': b'eyd2ZXJzaW9uJzogJzAnLCAnaWQnOiAnMTExMTE3NzItZjMwYi00OTFjLTZiYmItMWYzYmFkM2FmM2Y5JywgJ2RldGFpbHR5cGUnOiAnQVdTIEFQSSBDYWxsIHZpYSBDbG91ZFRyYWlsJywgJ3NvdXJjZSc6ICdhd3Muc2VjdXJpdHlodWInLCAnYWNjb3VudCc6ICc5MzQ3NTU5ODkxNzYnLCAndGltZSc6ICcyMDIxLTExLTIzVDIwOjQ2OjI2WicsICdyZWdpb24nOiAndXMtZWFzdC0xJywgJ3Jlc291cmNlcyc6IFtdLCAnZGV0YWlsJzogeydldmVudFZlcnNpb24nOiAnMS4wOCcsICd1c2VySWRlbnRpdHknOiB7J3R5cGUnOiAnQXNzdW1lZFJvbGUnLCAncHJpbmNpcGFsSWQnOiAnQVJPQTVUSTZNTzI0SFVLQUJFTTc2OnNndXB0YTE2JywgJ2Fybic6ICdhcm46YXdzOnN0czo6OTM0NzU1OTg5MTc2OmFzc3VtZWQtcm9sZS9VRU5UQVdTR1RTU0VDVVJJVFlIVUJFWS9zZ3VwdGExNicsICdhY2NvdW50SWQnOiAnOTM0NzU1OTg5MTc2JywgJ2FjY2Vzc0tleUlkJzogJ0FTSUE1VEk2TU8yNExSSENPWEdEJywgJ3Nlc3Npb25Db250ZXh0JzogeydzZXNzaW9uSXNzdWVyJzogeyd0eXBlJzogJ1JvbGUnLCAncHJpbmNpcGFsSWQnOiAnQVJPQTVUSTZNTzI0SFVLQUJFTTc2JywgJ2Fybic6ICdhcm46YXdzOmlhbTo6OTM0NzU1OTg5MTc2OnJvbGUvVUVOVEFXU0dUU1NFQ1VSSVRZSFVCRVknLCAnYWNjb3VudElkJzogJzkzNDc1NTk4OTE3NicsICd1c2VyTmFtZSc6ICdVRU5UQVdTR1RTU0VDVVJJVFlIVUJFWSd9LCAnd2ViSWRGZWRlcmF0aW9uRGF0YSc6IHt9LCAnYXR0cmlidXRlcyc6IHsnY3JlYXRpb25EYXRlJzogJzIwMjEtMTEtMjNUMTg6NDk6MDVaJywgJ21mYUF1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZWQnOiAnZmFsc2UnfX19LCAnZXZlbnRUaW1lJzogJzIwMjEtMTEtMjNUMjA6NDY6MjZaJywgJ2V2ZW50U291cmNlJzogJ3NlY3VyaXR5aHViLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb20nLCAnZXZlbnROYW1lJzogJ0JhdGNoRGlzYWJsZVN0YW5kYXJkcycsICdhd3NSZWdpb24nOiAndXMtZWFzdC0xJywgJ3NvdXJjZUlQQWRkcmVzcyc6ICcxMzcuMTE3LjQzLjE0NCcsICd1c2VyQWdlbnQnOiAnYXdzLWludGVybmFsLzMgYXdzLXNkay1qYXZhLzEuMTIuMTEyIExpbnV4LzUuNC4xNDctODMuMjU5LmFtem4yaW50Lng4Nl82NCBPcGVuSkRLXzY0LUJpdF9TZXJ2ZXJfVk0vMjUuMzEyLWIwNyBqYXZhLzEuOC4wXzMxMiB2ZW5kb3IvT3JhY2xlX0NvcnBvcmF0aW9uIGNmZy9yZXRyeS1tb2RlL3N0YW5kYXJkJywgJ3JlcXVlc3RQYXJhbWV0ZXJzJzogeydTdGFuZGFyZHNTdWJzY3JpcHRpb25Bcm5zJzogWydhcm46YXdzOnNlY3VyaXR5aHViOnVzLWVhc3QtMTo5MzQ3NTU5ODkxNzY6c3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uL2F3cy1mb3VuZGF0aW9uYWwtc2VjdXJpdHktYmVzdC1wcmFjdGljZXMvdi8xLjAuMCddfSwgJ3Jlc3BvbnNlRWxlbWVudHMnOiB7J1N0YW5kYXJkc1N1YnNjcmlwdGlvbnMnOiBbeydTdGFuZGFyZHNBcm4nOiAnYXJuOmF3czpzZWN1cml0eWh1Yjp1cy1lYXN0LTE6OnN0YW5kYXJkcy9hd3MtZm91bmRhdGlvbmFsLXNlY3VyaXR5LWJlc3QtcHJhY3RpY2VzL3YvMS4wLjAnLCAnU3RhbmRhcmRzSW5wdXQnOiB7fSwgJ1N0YW5kYXJkc1N0YXR1cyc6ICdERUxFVElORycsICdTdGFuZGFyZHNTdWJzY3JpcHRpb25Bcm4nOiAnYXJuOmF3czpzZWN1cml0eWh1Yjp1cy1lYXN0LTE6OTM0NzU1OTg5MTc2OnN1YnNjcmlwdGlvbi9hd3MtZm91bmRhdGlvbmFsLXNlY3VyaXR5LWJlc3QtcHJhY3RpY2VzL3YvMS4wLjAnLCAnU3RhbmRhcmRzU3RhdHVzUmVhc29uJzogeydTdGF0dXNSZWFzb25Db2RlJzogJ0lOVEVSTkFMX0VSUk9SJ319XX0sICdyZXF1ZXN0SUQnOiAnMDAyYzQ1YzItNmYxYy00YTA5LWE5YTctZjQ1OTY5MWFiYzRjJywgJ2V2ZW50SUQnOiAnYTUzZTA1NjktYjYwOC00Nzg5LThlNzctNGNlYjhlNTg2YzliJywgJ3JlYWRPbmx5JzogRmFsc2UsICdldmVudFR5cGUnOiAnQXdzQXBpQ2FsbCcsICdtYW5hZ2VtZW50RXZlbnQnOiBUcnVlLCAncmVjaXBpZW50QWNjb3VudElkJzogJzkzNDc1NTk4OTE3NicsICdldmVudENhdGVnb3J5JzogJ01hbmFnZW1lbnQnfX0K'}
```

---

Edit : Updated

I have updated my code as below and now i don't receive any error but the output has backward slash () after each and every key/value. how to avoid this ?

```
for record in event['records']:
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data']).decode('utf-8')       
        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': base64.b64encode(json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8') + b'\n').decode('utf-8')
        }
        output.append(output_record)  
 
    return {'records': output}
```

Output :

```
"{\"version\":\"0\",\"id\":\"bcdfaff3-ff56-b1ea-a341-0f0ed44380c6\",\"detail-type\":\"Security Hub Findings - Imported\",\"source\":\"aws.securityhub\",\"account\":\"934755989176\",\"time\":\"2021-11-24T16:47:00Z\",\"region\":\"us-east-1\",\"resources\":[\"arn:aws:securityhub:us-east-1::product/aws/securityhub/arn:aws:securityhub:us-east-1:934755989176:subscription/aws-foundational-security-best-practices/v/1.0.0/IAM.7/finding/3fbf88ba-b228-4caa-a4aa-5bee36b1b007\"],\"detail\":{\"findings\":[{\"ProductArn\":\"arn:aws:securityhub:us-east-1::product/aws/securityhub\",\"Types\":[\"Software and Configuration Checks/Industry and Regulatory Standards/AWS-Foundational-Security-Best-Practices\"],\"Description\":\"This AWS control checks whether the account password policy for IAM users uses the following recommended configurations: RequireUppercaseCharacters: true, RequireLowercaseCharacters: true, RequireSymbols: true, RequireNumbers: true, MinimumPasswordLength: 8.\",\"Compliance\":{\"Status\":\"PASSED\"},\"ProductName\":\"Security Hub\",\"FirstObservedAt\":\"2021-11-18T14:03:23.999Z\",\"CreatedAt\":\"2021-11-18T14:03:23.999Z\",\"LastObservedAt\":\"2021-11-24T16:46:54.212Z\",\"CompanyName\":\"AWS\",\"FindingProviderFields\":{\"Types\":[\"Software and Configuration Checks/Industry and Regulatory Standards/AWS-Foundational-Security-Best-Practices\"],\"Severity\":{\"Normalized\":0,\"Label\":\"INFORMATIONAL\",\"Product\":0,\"Original\":\"INFORMATIONAL\"}},\"ProductFields\":{\"StandardsArn\":\"arn:aws:securityhub:::standards/aws-foundational-security-best-practices/v/1.0.0\",\"StandardsSubscriptionArn\":\"arn:aws:securityhub:us-east-1:934755989176:subscription/aws-foundational-security-best-practices/v/1.0.0\",\"ControlId\":\"IAM.7\",\"RecommendationUrl\":\"https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/securityhub/IAM.7/remediation\",\"RelatedAWSResources:0/name\":\"securityhub-iam-password-policy-recommended-defaults-35610a74\",\"RelatedAWSResources:0/type\":\"AWS::Config::ConfigRule\",\"StandardsControlArn\":\"arn:aws:securityhub:us-east-1:934755989176:control/aws-foundational-security-best-practices/v/1.0.0/IAM.7\",\"aws/securityhub/ProductName\":\"Security Hub\",\"aws/securityhub/CompanyName\":\"AWS\",\"Resources:0/Id\":\"arn:aws:iam::934755989176:root\",\"aws/securityhub/FindingId\":\"arn:aws:securityhub:us-east-1::product/aws/securityhub/arn:aws:securityhub:us-east-1:934755989176:subscription/aws-foundational-security-best-practices/v/1.0.0/IAM.7/finding/3fbf88ba-b228-4caa-a4aa-5bee36b1b007\"},\"Remediation\":{\"Recommendation\":{\"Text\":\"For directions on how to fix this issue, consult the AWS Security Hub Foundational Security Best Practices documentation.\",\"Url\":\"https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/securityhub/IAM.7/remediation\"}},\"SchemaVersion\":\"2018-10-08\",\"GeneratorId\":\"aws-foundational-security-best-practices/v/1.0.0/IAM.7\",\"RecordState\":\"ACTIVE\",\"Title\":\"IAM.7 Password policies for IAM users should have strong configurations\",\"Workflow\":{\"Status\":\"RESOLVED\"},\"Severity\":{\"Normalized\":0,\"Label\":\"INFORMATIONAL\",\"Product\":0,\"Original\":\"INFORMATIONAL\"},\"UpdatedAt\":\"2021-11-24T16:46:49.775Z\",\"WorkflowState\":\"NEW\",\"AwsAccountId\":\"934755989176\",\"Region\":\"us-east-1\",\"Id\":\"arn:aws:securityhub:us-east-1:934755989176:subscription/aws-foundational-security-best-practices/v/1.0.0/IAM.7/finding/3fbf88ba-b228-4caa-a4aa-5bee36b1b007\",\"Resources\":[{\"Partition\":\"aws\",\"Type\":\"AwsAccount\",\"Region\":\"us-east-1\",\"Id\":\"AWS::::Account:934755989176\"}]}]}}"
```

Comment: Can you run print(output)? Let’s see what the data looks like.

Comment: I use the requests Lib…then I do print(output.json())

Comment: With just the Json lib…one of these answers will be your solution: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html…let me know if I can write any of my comments in an answer and get some rep points

Comment: What's in `output`?

Comment: you have a byte object in your dict

Comment: Where is the byte object ? Is it the problem ?

Comment: You need to put `.encode('utf-8')` at the end of `base64.b64encode(row_w_newline.encode('utf-8'))`, otherwise you're trying to put a `bytes` object into `output` which is not serializable as JSON. `b64encode` returns bytes, not a string, so you have to encode it as a string before it'll be valid to put into JSON. The `b` at the beginning of the `data` string (like `b'blah blah'`) indicated to me that that was what was going on.

Comment: @RandomDavis : Are you saying to make it like this ? row_w_newline = base64.b64encode(row_w_newline).encode('utf-8') ?

Comment: @Bokambo that'll probably work. doesn't look like `row_w_newline` needed encoding anyway, since it's a `str`.

Comment: @RandomDavis : Getting this error after making above change - a bytes-like object is required, not 'str': TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 23, in lambda_handler
row_w_newline = base64.b64encode(row_w_newline).encode('utf-8')
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str’

Comment: The backslashes you see in the string are just there to show that they are _literal_ double quotes rather than the end of the string. Try to `print` the value to see what it actually contains.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because you are sending a binary string in your json output when the method json.dumps is called it complains that doesn't know how to convert the string as text. I reproduced your error wiht this code:

```
import json
a = {'text':b'foovar'}
json.dumps(a)
```

Maybe you could just decode or encode your data when you send it or recieve it something like this

```
import json
a = {'text':b'foovar'.decode('ascii')}
json.dumps(a)
```

and in your client encode it and use base64 decode.

Your lambda function transform under the hood your response dictionary to json to do that it calls json.dumps.

### Final solution

just to replicate your actual case i created this code snippet:

```
test = {'recordId': '49624207526699472828556941664751397737727737843643580418000000', 'result': 'Ok', 'data': b'eyd2ZXJzaW9uJzogJzAnLCAnaWQnOiAnMTExMTE3NzItZjMwYi00OTFjLTZiYmItMWYzYmFkM2FmM2Y5JywgJ2RldGFpbHR5cGUnOiAnQVdTIEFQSSBDYWxsIHZpYSBDbG91ZFRyYWlsJywgJ3NvdXJjZSc6ICdhd3Muc2VjdXJpdHlodWInLCAnYWNjb3VudCc6ICc5MzQ3NTU5ODkxNzYnLCAndGltZSc6ICcyMDIxLTExLTIzVDIwOjQ2OjI2WicsICdyZWdpb24nOiAndXMtZWFzdC0xJywgJ3Jlc291cmNlcyc6IFtdLCAnZGV0YWlsJzogeydldmVudFZlcnNpb24nOiAnMS4wOCcsICd1c2VySWRlbnRpdHknOiB7J3R5cGUnOiAnQXNzdW1lZFJvbGUnLCAncHJpbmNpcGFsSWQnOiAnQVJPQTVUSTZNTzI0SFVLQUJFTTc2OnNndXB0YTE2JywgJ2Fybic6ICdhcm46YXdzOnN0czo6OTM0NzU1OTg5MTc2OmFzc3VtZWQtcm9sZS9VRU5UQVdTR1RTU0VDVVJJVFlIVUJFWS9zZ3VwdGExNicsICdhY2NvdW50SWQnOiAnOTM0NzU1OTg5MTc2JywgJ2FjY2Vzc0tleUlkJzogJ0FTSUE1VEk2TU8yNExSSENPWEdEJywgJ3Nlc3Npb25Db250ZXh0JzogeydzZXNzaW9uSXNzdWVyJzogeyd0eXBlJzogJ1JvbGUnLCAncHJpbmNpcGFsSWQnOiAnQVJPQTVUSTZNTzI0SFVLQUJFTTc2JywgJ2Fybic6ICdhcm46YXdzOmlhbTo6OTM0NzU1OTg5MTc2OnJvbGUvVUVOVEFXU0dUU1NFQ1VSSVRZSFVCRVknLCAnYWNjb3VudElkJzogJzkzNDc1NTk4OTE3NicsICd1c2VyTmFtZSc6ICdVRU5UQVdTR1RTU0VDVVJJVFlIVUJFWSd9LCAnd2ViSWRGZWRlcmF0aW9uRGF0YSc6IHt9LCAnYXR0cmlidXRlcyc6IHsnY3JlYXRpb25EYXRlJzogJzIwMjEtMTEtMjNUMTg6NDk6MDVaJywgJ21mYUF1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZWQnOiAnZmFsc2UnfX19LCAnZXZlbnRUaW1lJzogJzIwMjEtMTEtMjNUMjA6NDY6MjZaJywgJ2V2ZW50U291cmNlJzogJ3NlY3VyaXR5aHViLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb20nLCAnZXZlbnROYW1lJzogJ0JhdGNoRGlzYWJsZVN0YW5kYXJkcycsICdhd3NSZWdpb24nOiAndXMtZWFzdC0xJywgJ3NvdXJjZUlQQWRkcmVzcyc6ICcxMzcuMTE3LjQzLjE0NCcsICd1c2VyQWdlbnQnOiAnYXdzLWludGVybmFsLzMgYXdzLXNkay1qYXZhLzEuMTIuMTEyIExpbnV4LzUuNC4xNDctODMuMjU5LmFtem4yaW50Lng4Nl82NCBPcGVuSkRLXzY0LUJpdF9TZXJ2ZXJfVk0vMjUuMzEyLWIwNyBqYXZhLzEuOC4wXzMxMiB2ZW5kb3IvT3JhY2xlX0NvcnBvcmF0aW9uIGNmZy9yZXRyeS1tb2RlL3N0YW5kYXJkJywgJ3JlcXVlc3RQYXJhbWV0ZXJzJzogeydTdGFuZGFyZHNTdWJzY3JpcHRpb25Bcm5zJzogWydhcm46YXdzOnNlY3VyaXR5aHViOnVzLWVhc3QtMTo5MzQ3NTU5ODkxNzY6c3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uL2F3cy1mb3VuZGF0aW9uYWwtc2VjdXJpdHktYmVzdC1wcmFjdGljZXMvdi8xLjAuMCddfSwgJ3Jlc3BvbnNlRWxlbWVudHMnOiB7J1N0YW5kYXJkc1N1YnNjcmlwdGlvbnMnOiBbeydTdGFuZGFyZHNBcm4nOiAnYXJuOmF3czpzZWN1cml0eWh1Yjp1cy1lYXN0LTE6OnN0YW5kYXJkcy9hd3MtZm91bmRhdGlvbmFsLXNlY3VyaXR5LWJlc3QtcHJhY3RpY2VzL3YvMS4wLjAnLCAnU3RhbmRhcmRzSW5wdXQnOiB7fSwgJ1N0YW5kYXJkc1N0YXR1cyc6ICdERUxFVElORycsICdTdGFuZGFyZHNTdWJzY3JpcHRpb25Bcm4nOiAnYXJuOmF3czpzZWN1cml0eWh1Yjp1cy1lYXN0LTE6OTM0NzU1OTg5MTc2OnN1YnNjcmlwdGlvbi9hd3MtZm91bmRhdGlvbmFsLXNlY3VyaXR5LWJlc3QtcHJhY3RpY2VzL3YvMS4wLjAnLCAnU3RhbmRhcmRzU3RhdHVzUmVhc29uJzogeydTdGF0dXNSZWFzb25Db2RlJzogJ0lOVEVSTkFMX0VSUk9SJ319XX0sICdyZXF1ZXN0SUQnOiAnMDAyYzQ1YzItNmYxYy00YTA5LWE5YTctZjQ1OTY5MWFiYzRjJywgJ2V2ZW50SUQnOiAnYTUzZTA1NjktYjYwOC00Nzg5LThlNzctNGNlYjhlNTg2YzliJywgJ3JlYWRPbmx5JzogRmFsc2UsICdldmVudFR5cGUnOiAnQXdzQXBpQ2FsbCcsICdtYW5hZ2VtZW50RXZlbnQnOiBUcnVlLCAncmVjaXBpZW50QWNjb3VudElkJzogJzkzNDc1NTk4OTE3NicsICdldmVudENhdGVnb3J5JzogJ01hbmFnZW1lbnQnfX0K'}
test['data'] = test['data'].decode('utf-8')
json.dumps(test)
```

works fine. I would recommend to read some examples on serialization if you are struggling with this

Comment: I am not using json.dumps in my above code. Can you please suggest what change you are suggesting referring above code ?

Comment: looking at the comments @Bokambo has suggested something similar, but remember to use `decode` over your base64 response NOT `encode`

Comment: Thank you Carlos for your suggestion but it is not clear to me what you are trying to say ? Can you please explain ?

Comment: Are you suggesting this ?  row_w_newline = base64.b64decode(row_w_newline.encode('utf-8'))

Comment: your lambda_handler functions returns a dictionary, but you have binary data on it.  you can´t have binary data on a json wich is a plain text format for that reason you must convert your binary string stored in your `row_w_newline` variable to string. To achieve that you must decode it

Comment: something like this
row_w_newline = base64.b64decode(row_w_newline).decode('utf-8')

Comment: Thank you Carlos and where you are suggesting to use .decode('ascii')} in above code ?

Comment: The thing which is calling your lambda expects to receive a result which it can serialize. The fundamental problem has been explained several times already; the `'data':` field contains a `bytes` object, which cannot be serialized. You have to change it into something which can.

Comment: @Carlos : It gives me below error after changing it to - base64.b64decode(row_w_newline).decode('utf-8') Error : Incorrect padding: Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 23, in lambda_handler
row_w_newline = base64.b64decode(row_w_newline).decode('utf-8')
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: @tripleee : I totally understand the underlying problem , but none of the solution worked which i tried so far so asking for suggestions.

Comment: try other encodings like 'utf-16', 'utf-32', 'ascii'

Comment: The data in your example is already encoded as base64, for no good reason as the structure inside is pure ASCII. If you want to keep it as base64 data, `row_w_newline.encode('us-ascii')` converts the base64 `bytes` data to a pure ASCII string containing the same base64 payload.

Comment: Please see my updated code above.

Comment: Does the above code looks good ? Is this what you guys were recommending ?

Answer (score 0):

This code helped to resolve above issue

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    for record in event['records']:
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data']).decode('utf-8')
        remove_special_char = json.loads(payload, object_pairs_hook=clean_keys)
        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': base64.b64encode(json.dumps(remove_special_char).encode('utf-8') + b'\n').decode('utf-8')
        }
        output.append(output_record)

    print('Processed {} records.'.format(len(event['records'])))
    return {'records': output}
```